# Angular Provider useValue over directly using constant

Tags: angular, constants, provider

```
"export const HERO_DI_CONFIG: AppConfig = {
  apiEndpoint: 'api.heroes.com',
  title: 'Dependency Injection'
};"
```

example 1 :
One of the Provider is useValue

```
providers: [{ provide: APP_CONFIG, useValue: HERO_DI_CONFIG }]

constructor(@Inject(APP_CONFIG) config: AppConfig) {
  this.title = config.title;
}
```

example 2:
directly import APP_CONFIG constant from App.Config
and use like this :

```
let varibaleName = HERO_DI_CONFIG.apiEndpoint;
```

what advantage we are getting by using a useValue over directly accessing Constant from App.config

Comment: Simple example: in a test you could provide a mock endpoint to use instead.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of a library (or a shared feature module) it's better to use the token injector because it could be overloaded and thus it's more flexible than a constant.

There are many libraries out there that use this method to overload constants (angular/fire among others).